# Check-ToolButton. I need an Event before showing the menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a couple of buttons on a toolbar with the Style defined as tbsDropDown and a Popup menu assigned.

I need to check if there are any records in the Database before showing the Menu. I have added btnFilter.CheckMenuDropDown; to the main part of the button so I am able to check there, but the "Down arrow" button shows the Popup. I need to intervene at that point with an Event of "BeforePopup"

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is NGLN's assumption true that you want to prevent the menu from appearing?

Answer (score 2):

First, `TToolButton.CheckMenuDropDown` is a routine which always drops down the menu, but returns False when it is not able to.

I understand that you want to disable the dropdown menu when there are no records in de dataset.

Possible solutions:

- Disable the tool button (or temporarily set the `PopupMenu` property to nil) when there are no records, and vise versa. This is preferably to be done by attaching an action to the button.
- Interpose the `TToolButton` class and override `CheckMenuDown`:

  ```
  type
    TToolButton = class(ComCtrls.TToolButton)
    private
      FCanDropDown: Boolean;
    public
      function CheckMenuDropdown: Boolean; override;
      property CanDropDown: Boolean read FCanDropDown write FCanDropDown;
    end;

  function TToolButton.CheckMenuDropdown: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := FCanDropDown and (inherited CheckMenuDropdown);
  end;
  ```

  But this is not a designtime solution and you have to set the `CanDropDown` property at runtime accordingly.
- Create a new component and publish the `CanDropDown` property in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Before the menu appears, the its [`OnPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.OnPopup) event fires. That gives you an opportunity to modify the menu's contents before you finally show it.